# Creating an ssh tunnel over http_proxy for software activation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, ssh-tunnel, windows-server-2012-r2, http-proxy

Environment:  Corporate internal network, with only a proxy server and proxy authentication as a window out.  Installing a piece of software on Windows Server 2008 R2 (or 2012 R2).

Scenario:  I have an application that I need to install and activate.  The connection for activation happens over ssh from the software installer on the local server to remote activation servers.  I know the IP address of all possible remote servers used by the application for activation.

Is there a way to create a tunnel (Perhaps with HTTP_PROXY environment variable?) that the application will use (any windows application) to activate via ssh?

I've been researching the HTTP_PROXY windows environment variable and putty.  I've found a few resources online but haven't been able to put anything together that works.

Side Note:  I know my HTTP_PROXY environment variable is working because I can use gem to install remote ruby packages.

```
set http_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@ProxyServer:Port
```

Comment: only certain software will look for an http_proxy variable. Based on what you say, apparently 'gem' is one of them.   wget is another.

Comment: there is a program called corkscrew.. i'm not sure if it will help you but maybe.  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/using-corkscrew-to-tunnel-ssh-over-http/  http://agroman.net/corkscrew/  You can get corkscrew in cygwin (and openssh too)